# Bootstrap's dropdown hidden by datatables

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap to create a button with a DropDown menu for each row in a DataTables grid, but the data container from DataTables is using "overflow: hidden" what is making the DropDown to be cut.

I cannot just switch to "overflow: auto" as this will cause to appear an unnecessary vertical scrollbar.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/julianonunes/Qa6y2/7/)

HTML

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="pretty" id="example"></table>
```

JS

```
/* API method to get paging information */
$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnPagingInfo = function (oSettings) {
    return {
        "iStart": oSettings._iDisplayStart,
            "iEnd": oSettings.fnDisplayEnd(),
            "iLength": oSettings._iDisplayLength,
            "iTotal": oSettings.fnRecordsTotal(),
            "iFilteredTotal": oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay(),
            "iPage": oSettings._iDisplayLength === -1 ? 0 : Math.ceil(oSettings._iDisplayStart / oSettings._iDisplayLength),
            "iTotalPages": oSettings._iDisplayLength === -1 ? 0 : Math.ceil(oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay() / oSettings._iDisplayLength)
    };
}

/* Bootstrap style pagination control */
$.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oPagination, {
    "bootstrap": {
        "fnInit": function (oSettings, nPaging, fnDraw) {
            var oLang = oSettings.oLanguage.oPaginate;
            var fnClickHandler = function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if (oSettings.oApi._fnPageChange(oSettings, e.data.action)) {
                    fnDraw(oSettings);
                }
            };

            $(nPaging).addClass('pagination').append(
                '<ul>' +
                '<li class="prev disabled"><a href="#">&larr; ' + oLang.sPrevious + '</a></li>' +
                '<li class="next disabled"><a href="#">' + oLang.sNext + ' &rarr; </a></li>' +
                '</ul>');
            var els = $('a', nPaging);
            $(els[0]).bind('click.DT', {
                action: "previous"
            }, fnClickHandler);
            $(els[1]).bind('click.DT', {
                action: "next"
            }, fnClickHandler);
        },

            "fnUpdate": function (oSettings, fnDraw) {
            var iListLength = 5;
            var oPaging = oSettings.oInstance.fnPagingInfo();
            var an = oSettings.aanFeatures.p;
            var i, j, sClass, iStart, iEnd, iHalf = Math.floor(iListLength / 2);

            if (oPaging.iTotalPages < iListLength) {
                iStart = 1;
                iEnd = oPaging.iTotalPages;
            } else if (oPaging.iPage <= iHalf) {
                iStart = 1;
                iEnd = iListLength;
            } else if (oPaging.iPage >= (oPaging.iTotalPages - iHalf)) {
                iStart = oPaging.iTotalPages - iListLength + 1;
                iEnd = oPaging.iTotalPages;
            } else {
                iStart = oPaging.iPage - iHalf + 1;
                iEnd = iStart + iListLength - 1;
            }

            for (i = 0, iLen = an.length; i < iLen; i++) {
                // Remove the middle elements
                $('li:gt(0)', an[i]).filter(':not(:last)').remove();

                // Add the new list items and their event handlers
                for (j = iStart; j <= iEnd; j++) {
                    sClass = (j == oPaging.iPage + 1) ? 'class="active"' : '';
                    $('<li ' + sClass + '><a href="#">' + j + '</a></li>')
                        .insertBefore($('li:last', an[i])[0])
                        .bind('click', function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        oSettings._iDisplayStart = (parseInt($('a', this).text(), 10) - 1) * oPaging.iLength;
                        fnDraw(oSettings);
                    });
                }

                // Add / remove disabled classes from the static elements
                if (oPaging.iPage === 0) {
                    $('li:first', an[i]).addClass('disabled');
                } else {
                    $('li:first', an[i]).removeClass('disabled');
                }

                if (oPaging.iPage === oPaging.iTotalPages - 1 || oPaging.iTotalPages === 0) {
                    $('li:last', an[i]).addClass('disabled');
                } else {
                    $('li:last', an[i]).removeClass('disabled');
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

/* Table initialisation */
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').dataTable({
        "aaData": [
        /* Reduced data set */ ['<div class="btn-group" style="float: left">' +
                                '<a class="btn btn-small dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Actions' +
                                    '<span class="caret"></span>' +
                                '</a>' +
                                '<ul class="dropdown-menu">' +
                                    '<li><a href="#">Approve</a></li>' +
                                    '<li><a href="#">View</a></li>' +
                                '</ul>' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '<a href="#" id="editButton" class="btn btn-small"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>' +
                            '<a href="#" class="btn btn-small deleteButton"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>', "Internet Explorer 4.0", "Win 95+", 4, "X"],
            ['<div class="btn-group" style="float: left">' +
                                '<a class="btn btn-small dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Actions' +
                                    '<span class="caret"></span>' +
                                '</a>' +
                                '<ul class="dropdown-menu">' +
                                    '<li><a href="#">Approve</a></li>' +
                                    '<li><a href="#">View</a></li>' +
                                '</ul>' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '<a href="#" id="editButton" class="btn btn-small"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>' +
                            '<a href="#" class="btn btn-small deleteButton"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>', "Internet Explorer 5.0", "Win 95+", 5, "C"],
            ['<div class="btn-group" style="float: left">' +
                                '<a class="btn btn-small dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Actions' +
                                    '<span class="caret"></span>' +
                                '</a>' +
                                '<ul class="dropdown-menu">' +
                                    '<li><a href="#">Approve</a></li>' +
                                    '<li><a href="#">View</a></li>' +
                                '</ul>' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '<a href="#" id="editButton" class="btn btn-small"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>' +
                            '<a href="#" class="btn btn-small deleteButton"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>', "Internet Explorer 5.5", "Win 95+", 5.5, "A"],
            ['<div class="btn-group" style="float: left">' +
                                '<a class="btn btn-small dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Actions' +
                                    '<span class="caret"></span>' +
                                '</a>' +
                                '<ul class="dropdown-menu">' +
                                    '<li><a href="#">Approve</a></li>' +
                                    '<li><a href="#">View</a></li>' +
                                '</ul>' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '<a href="#" id="editButton" class="btn btn-small"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>' +
                            '<a href="#" class="btn btn-small deleteButton"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>', "Internet Explorer 6.0", "Win 98+", 6, "A"],
            ['<div class="btn-group" style="float: left">' +
                                '<a class="btn btn-small dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Actions' +
                                    '<span class="caret"></span>' +
                                '</a>' +
                                '<ul class="dropdown-menu">' +
                                    '<li><a href="#">Approve</a></li>' +
                                    '<li><a href="#">View</a></li>' +
                                '</ul>' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '<a href="#" id="editButton" class="btn btn-small"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>' +
                            '<a href="#" class="btn btn-small deleteButton"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>', "Internet Explorer 7.0", "Win XP SP2+", 7, "A"],
            ['<div class="btn-group" style="float: left">' +
                                '<a class="btn btn-small dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Actions' +
                                    '<span class="caret"></span>' +
                                '</a>' +
                                '<ul class="dropdown-menu">' +
                                    '<li><a href="#">Approve</a></li>' +
                                    '<li><a href="#">View</a></li>' +
                                '</ul>' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '<a href="#" id="editButton" class="btn btn-small"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>' +
                            '<a href="#" class="btn btn-small deleteButton"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>', "Firefox 1.5", "Win 98+ / OSX.2+", 1.8, "A"],
            ['<div class="btn-group" style="float: left">' +
                                '<a class="btn btn-small dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Actions' +
                                    '<span class="caret"></span>' +
                                '</a>' +
                                '<ul class="dropdown-menu">' +
                                    '<li><a href="#">Approve</a></li>' +
                                    '<li><a href="#">View</a></li>' +
                                '</ul>' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '<a href="#" id="editButton" class="btn btn-small"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>' +
                            '<a href="#" class="btn btn-small deleteButton"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>', "Firefox 2", "Win 98+ / OSX.2+", 1.8, "A"],
            ['<div class="btn-group" style="float: left">' +
                                '<a class="btn btn-small dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Actions' +
                                    '<span class="caret"></span>' +
                                '</a>' +
                                '<ul class="dropdown-menu">' +
                                    '<li><a href="#">Approve</a></li>' +
                                    '<li><a href="#">View</a></li>' +
                                '</ul>' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '<a href="#" id="editButton" class="btn btn-small"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>' +
                            '<a href="#" class="btn btn-small deleteButton"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>', "Firefox 3", "Win 2k+ / OSX.3+", 1.9, "A"]
        ],
            "aoColumns": [{
            "sTitle": "Engine"
        }, {
            "sTitle": "Browser"
        }, {
            "sTitle": "Platform"
        }, {
            "sTitle": "Version",
            "sClass": "center"
        }, {
            "sTitle": "Grade",
            "sClass": "center"
        }],

            'sScrollX': "100%",
            'sScrollXInner': "150%",
            'bScrollCollapse': true,
            'bAutoWidth': false,
            'bDeferRender': true,
            'bLengthChange': false, "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
            "oLanguage": {
            "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"
        }
    });
    $('.acoes').dropdown();
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I miss understand you, but I think I don't have such problem: http://chrpics.eu.pn/view.php?file=user/Fnwoh&amp;filename=screenshot.png Is that dropdown what you meant?

Comment: @chris Click the button in the last row.

Comment: Ok, like this: http://chrpics.eu.pn/view.php?file=user/52PA8&amp;filename=screenshot2.png (I didn't changed anything from your fiddle, btw)

Comment: Here is what happens if I don't use the inner scrollbar to go down: http://s2.postimg.org/41polkiuh/Capture.png . The problem is that even with 3 rows of data and much space to use, DataTables defines a fixed height which causes unnecessary scrollbar.

Comment: How about using `overflow: visible;` like this http://jsfiddle.net/sulfureous/QAjwK/ ?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865807/datatable-and-bootstrap-css-z-index-error

Comment: @Cole"Cole9"Johnson hm? if you read his question, he did mentioned that link.

Comment: @chris I know. I'm saying, just because that question doesn't have an answer doesn't mean it's ok to ask the question, but changed to fit your situation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, after the comments we had, I realized what you want:

You have a `<div>` element with `overflow:auto`, and you want that an element inside of that `<div>` (the `<ul>` where the menu is), to "*escape*" from the overflow rule and **appear floating, overriding the overflow rule from its ancestor.**

But I'm afraid that is **not possible**. The closest thing you could do is:

- Use javascript to create the `<ul>` with the menu **outside** the `<div>` with `overflow:auto`, and then use position absolute to set it where it should go, or
- Use javascript to auto scroll at the bottom once that dropdown menu is activated, by adding something like an event listener to the the last dropdown.

The second option seems more elegant and less 'hackish'. (Personally I would just ignore that problem, but if I have to choose, I would go for the second option)

Comment: I solved disabling the scrolling option of DataTables, but your suggestion would help me too.

Comment: I wrote two samples of both proposals:   
- Move outside: http://jsfiddle.net/Sc9r3/1/   
- Scroll: http://jsfiddle.net/5TNvU/2/

Comment: @Marc : This is really good suggestion, But I found that it's not working perfect with Safari Latest Browser. When loading page first time, it popup perfectly, then clicking next time, the top & Left of Menu is changed. And I think the next time the position of menu = last top + height of menu ...

Comment: @Marc, you should write it up as an answer, as it works well. Just one thing to note for future visitors - there is a conflict between bootstrap.js and the DataTables bootstrap-included js which causes the hide event to be fired immediately after the show event, so the menu does not get shown. To avoid this, don't include the bootstrap js at the same time as datatables.

Answer (score 8):

I got the same problem ! Resolved removing overflow properties in component.css

```
.table-scrollable {
  width: 100%;
/*  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;*/
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  margin: 10px 0 !important;
}
```

Or add to your custom.css (called after bootstrap)

```
.table-scrollable { 
    overflow-x: visible; 
    overflow-y: visible; 
}
```

Comment: Or add to your custom.css (called after bootstrap)

.table-scrollable {
    overflow-x: visible;
    overflow-y: visible;
}

Comment: worked for me inline mode `<style>...</style>` just before the `<table>` declaration.

Comment: Amazing answer! Simply removed `overflow: auto;` and it's fine now!

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me : Datatable + fixed headers + bootstrap dropdown in header

```
.dataTables_scrollHead{
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Added to custom css after all others

Comment: After a long search found this and It worked !! TYSM :)

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was to adjust the positioning of the Bootstrap dropdown menu to `fixed` and move the menu to a specific section of the screen.

And it works with mobile view since it's relative to the window.

```css
table .dropdown-menu {
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 50% !important;
    left: 92% !important;
    transform: translate(-92%, -50%) !important;
}
```

This way you can keep the behavior of the `scroller` extension, `scrollX` and `scrollY` properties of `DataTables`.

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

Override DataTable css rule for the .dataTables_scrollHead selector worked for me

```
.dataTables_scrollHead{
    position: static !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    .ngx-datatable {
  display: block;
  overflow: visible !important;
}

    .table-responsive {
  overflow: visible !important;
}



 .table-responsive .dropdown-menu {
  position: static !important;
  overflow: visible !important;
  top: 50% !important;
  left: 92% !important;
  transform: translate(-92%, -0%) !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The quick and easy fix to this is define `div.dataTables_scrollHead:hover { overflow: hidden !important }` then if still problem persists then another quick solution that worked for me is define height to scroll head and margin-top in - to scroll body
for example:

```
    div.dataTables_scrollHead {
            height: 250px;
        }
div.dataTables_scrollBody {
        margin-top: -190px;
    }
```

That should fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For bootstrap 4 add `data-boundary="window"` property to `div` that has class `dropdown-menu`.

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" data-boundary="window">
```

And set the `position` of parent container to `Fixed`. In this case the parent container is `btn-group`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="btn-group" style="position:Fixed">
   <div class="dropdown-menu" data-boundary="window">
   </div>
</div>
```

You can move style attribute to CSS file as well.

```
table .btn-group {
    position: fixed !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [bootstrap doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/dropdowns/#options), just add data-boundary="window" to its toggle.

```
<a class="btn btn-small dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-boundary="window" href="#">Actions<span class="caret"></span></a>
```