# How do I add a dropdown button on each row of a jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am using [datatables](http://datatables.net/) plugin to display data as a table in my application.

I want to add the [Bootstrap Dropdown Buttons](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns) or [Javascript Dropdowns](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns) on each row of my table. But the dropdown part goes hidden under the table rows, and I am not able to fix it.

The html for the table would be:

```html
<table id="swcmtable" cellspacing="0" width="100%"
       class="table table-striped table-hover dt-responsive" >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> ID</th>  
      <th>Modifier</th>  
      <th> Created Time</th> 
      <th> Modified Time</th> 
      <th> Edit</th> 
      <th> Actions</th>  
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>Admin</td>
      <td>10/06/2014</td>
      <td>11/02/2015</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
          Edit
        </button>
      </td>

      <td>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button id="dLabel" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" 
                  aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown trigger
            <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>

    </tr>

  </tbody>                        
</table>
```

I initialize the datatable as follows:

```js
$('#swcmtable').DataTable({
  "iDisplayLength" : 50,
  "aaSorting": []
});
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: It doesn't look like it's going under.  Do you want it to look different from [this screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/XAqNpGK.png).  Here's a [demo in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/gc7xkmtc/)

Comment: I will go under if there are more than one rows in the table.

Comment: [Nope](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/gc7xkmtc/1/) | [Proof](http://i.imgur.com/2jJkfCC.gif).  It's possible that you have some local CSS that's interfering with the solution.  I'd take the working version and start adding your css in blocks until you find the offending code.  Or take the current version and start disabling rules in the inspector.

Comment: I dont know why, but in my page I can see that even for 1 row, the dropdown goes under the table row......

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138785/bootstraps-dropdown-hidden-by-datatables)...check that out and see if it solves it for you.

Comment: I understand that the drop-downs of the drop-down button gets hidden because of the following style I am using  `overflow: hidden;`, which is actually important since some of the fields of my table might contain large values of which extra text must be hidden. Is there any way that I can enable overflow only for the div of the drop-down buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the details you provided, it is clear that you are using a custom style to hide text overflow in your data-table. Also since you have specified that this style is important, you can try to hide text overflow only for the column where you need to truncate the extra text and do not apply this style for entire table.

Use something like:

```
table.dataTable td:nth-child(2) 
{
    max-width:120px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;  
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

This code will hide text overflow only for the second column of the table and the remaining columns will not b affected.
I believe this should work in your case